# Validation rule

Tags: validation, salesforce2salesforce

Permission on quotes: all users should be able to see quotes of everybody
USA users: they should be able to modify quotes of any USA user (but not of other users)
Other users: they should be able to modify their own quotes but not the quotes of other users

quote is a visualforce page

i wrote the validation like this it is working for the other user fine it  is not working for usa user could some body help me

```
(if(($Profile.Id<>'00e90000000erfV'),(AND(
((ISCHANGED( Subject__c)) || (ISCHANGED(From_Phone__c))||
(ISCHANGED( CurrencyIsoCode )) || (ISCHANGED( Opportunity_Name__c ))||(ISCHANGED( Account_Name__c )) || (ISCHANGED( RFQ_Date__c ))||(ISCHANGED( RFQ_Reference__c )) || (ISCHANGED( Quote_Validity__c ))||(ISCHANGED( Delivery_Condition__c )) || (ISCHANGED( Payment_Terms__c ))||(ISCHANGED( From_Email__c )) || (ISCHANGED( Agent_Sales_Rep__c ))||(ISCHANGED( Copy_To3__c )) || (ISCHANGED( Contact_Name__c ))||(ISCHANGED( Phone__c )) || (ISCHANGED(Fax__c))||(ISCHANGED( Email__c)) || (ISCHANGED( Bill_To_Street__c )||(ISCHANGED( Bill_To_City__c )) || (ISCHANGED( Bill_To_State_Province__c ))||(ISCHANGED(Bill_To_Zip_Postal_Code__c)))),
OwnerId <> $User.Id
)),false))
||
((if(($Profile.Id='00e90000000erfV'),NOT(AND(
((ISCHANGED( Subject__c)) || (ISCHANGED(From_Phone__c))||
(ISCHANGED( CurrencyIsoCode )) || (ISCHANGED( Opportunity_Name__c ))||(ISCHANGED( Account_Name__c )) || (ISCHANGED( RFQ_Date__c ))||(ISCHANGED( RFQ_Reference__c )) || (ISCHANGED( Quote_Validity__c ))||(ISCHANGED( Delivery_Condition__c )) || (ISCHANGED( Payment_Terms__c ))||(ISCHANGED( From_Email__c )) || (ISCHANGED( Agent_Sales_Rep__c ))||(ISCHANGED( Copy_To3__c )) || (ISCHANGED( Contact_Name__c ))||(ISCHANGED( Phone__c )) || (ISCHANGED(Fax__c))||(ISCHANGED( Email__c)) || (ISCHANGED( Bill_To_Street__c )||(ISCHANGED( Bill_To_City__c )) || (ISCHANGED( Bill_To_State_Province__c ))||(ISCHANGED(Bill_To_Zip_Postal_Code__c))))
)),false))
```

the problem the usa user can able to edit other country quote .how can i do this one that usa user has to edit his or anybodies  usa region quotes but not other countries but they can able to read other country records

one profile with usa user is there profile-id='00e90000000erfV'.
remaining profiles of other user

Comment: Should users be able to see ALL quotes globally, or is this also limited by region such as the USA ?

Comment: no user able to see all quotes globally

Comment: Its not clear from what's posted above what you're using to differentiate between US and non US opportunities. For example, I don't see Country listed as one of the fields you're using. It would be very helpful if you told us what field differentiates between a US and non-US quote. Are you using Record Types to differentiate regions? If you are, that may be what you need to include in your validation rule to fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

are you using roles at all? it seems like this would be easily accomplished using permissions.

quotes
org wide default of public read

create either a role or a public group of which all USA users are members

sharing rule of any quotes owned by those USA users granting read/write on all USA users